# Vue.js - Element UI - Breaking changes select dropdown object and value-key

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue-js 2.4` and last version of `element-ui 1.4.1`

I have some drop down to select from a list of options, and each option is an object. Before the last update, everything was fine but now I'm facing several problems with the `select`. Especially the label displayed does not match the actual selected option.

> Breaking change:
>
> Select when value is an object, value-key is required as its unique
>   identity key, #5897

#### Questions

I'd like to know how to use the new `value-key`, I tried several things but it does not seem to change the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to what @poke points out here is what was helpful and fix the issue

```
 <el-select v-model="value" value-key="id">
            <el-option
              v-for="item in options"
              :label="item.label"
              :key="item.id"
             :value="item">
            </el-option>
</el-select>
```

Comment: Can you check whether you need both `value-key="id"` *and* `:key="item.id"`? I believe using just either of these should work.

Comment: it is working well without `:key` but then you have a warning from `vue compilator`  `component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys` So I suggest using both

Comment: Unknown custom element: <el-select> - did you register the component correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I cannot really understand what [the pull request is about](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/pull/5897) but looking at the changes, it appears that you need to specify how the objects are identified.

Apparently, you have to specify which property of the custom object will be used by setting the [`valueKey` attribute](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/pull/5897/files#diff-77681c030d3f0bb43a843a628ce7018cR199) on the `el-select` element. By default, this is `'value'`, so if your custom object has a `value` member and that can be used as the identifier, then that should already work. For all other objects, you can set the `valueKey` attribute accordingly.